# "Unsupported type java.lang.Class" error when checking ApexPages.Action with ISNULL

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, error

I have a custom component which doesn't use a Custom Controller.
On of the optional attribute is of Type ApexPages.Action.

The component renders a command button only when this attribute was set. It should. But intead saving this code in the IDE gives me a:

> Unsupported type java.lang.Class encountered.

```
<apex:component >
   <apex:attribute name="text" type="String" description="..." />
   <apex:attribute name="proceedAction" type="ApexPages.Action" description="..." />

   <apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail" rendered="{!ISBLANK(proceedAction)}">
       ...
       </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

The problem is that neighter ISNULL() nor ISBLANK() nor any other check seems to work in the rendered attribute.

What am I doing wrong? **I am only looking for solutions that work WITHOUT the addition of a custom controller class!**

Comment: I would surmise that the SFDC formula language does not support as operand anything of type: `java.lang.Class` which is what `ApexPages.Action` is. Can your calling VF pages pass an additional attribute of type boolean when the calling page 'knows' there is no action method for the use case?

Comment: Might be true, but there must be a way to find out if optional attribute were set or not. And without introducing a redundant Boolean attribute. :-(

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else encounters this error and is directed to this page:
I experienced the exact same error and verified that it happens both when attempting to deploy a VisualForce page from VSCode via CLI and in the SF Developer Console.
After much banging my head against the wall and commenting out pieces until I could find the source, I discovered that the RecordSetVar value for my standardListController happened to begin with the phrase "Class", which seems to be confusing Salesforce since it is a keyword of sorts.
That being said, I don't see anything standing out in the above code which could be setting Salesforce off as it did with me, but figured it would be a good idea to share this for posterity regardless!

tldr; check for "keywords" in your variable and expression values!